# JavaScript (JQuery) Global Var not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global

Why does this not work? I thought that if I set the "prw" and "prh" vars outside the function where they are calculated, but within the scoping function, it would work. But it doesn't! What do I do wrong?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

            var wrap = document.getElementById('imdiv');
            var img = wrap.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

            var prw;
            var prh;

            $("<img/>")
                .attr("src", $(img)
                .attr("src"))
                .load(function() {
                    prw = this.width;
                    prh = this.height;
            });

            console.log('prw ~ ', prw);
            console.log('prh ~ ', prh);
    });
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with scope. `.load()` is async. You'll need to do all the work in the function you pass in.

Comment: That's some funky looking code, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: OK, but how do I make it global?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's global, the console logs are called before you set a value to the variables

Comment: There is only one way to do this, move the console logs inside the load function

Comment: what do you mean by passing a `function` as the first parameter to `.load()`? It seems jQuery need an **url**. See [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). And I think you're meaning `$('<img/>').on('load')` or `$('<img/>').onload()`.

Comment: @Dylengleng - http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @RobH You're right. I missed this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
var prw;
var prh;

$(document).ready(function() {

var wrap = document.getElementById('imdiv');
var img = wrap.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

$("<img/>")
.attr("src", $(img)
.attr("src"))
.load(function() {
    prw = this.width;
    prh = this.height;
    return doStuff()
})
});

function doStuff(){
    console.log('prw ~ ', prw);
    console.log('prh ~ ', prh);
}
```

Comment: You can't return a function from an async call, but it somehow works as the function is called after the load has completed, but it really doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is nothing to do with your global variables.Only problem is you have print the values of variables before setting values to them.Load function will get call once the image gets loaded to the dom.

This execute first. still the values are not defined

```
console.log('prw ~ ', prw);
console.log('prh ~ ', prh);
```

after that this will get execute.

```
prw = this.width;
prh = this.height;
```

if you want to see the correct values you should print the values just after you set it

```
$("<img/>")
    .attr("src", $(img)
    .attr("src"))
      .load(function() {
            prw = this.width;
            prh = this.height;
            console.log('prw ~ ', prw);
            console.log('prh ~ ', prh);
       });
```

Comment: OK, but I'd like to use these values somewhere else. That's why I'd like to have them as global :P

Comment: Then you will have to wait till the image get loaded and set values correctly :-)

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring prw and prh again inside
    $(document).ready
so within that block you are creating two local variables with the same names than the global ones thus, because of JavaScript scope rules, your are accessing the local variables instead the globals.

Consider the next example:

```
var x = 3;

function f()
{
  var x;
  x = 2;
  alert(x);
}

f();

alert(x);
```

The output will be 2 and 3.

Comment: So how would I make the vars within .load(function() global then?

Comment: Move "var prw; var prh;" lines to the first line of your code.

Comment: That isn't the problem. The variable's scope is fine.